# How to change interface loopback adapter address in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, networking, loopback, ipconfig

Hi I created new loopback adapter in Windows 7 using:

```
devcon.exe install %windir%\inf\netloop.inf *msloop
```

Then if I execute ipconifg

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe40::234d:4e0d:b111:104%32
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 160.1.1.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

When I tried to change the address( I Just want to change the address but I can't find how to do that, so I try to change all address, subnet mask and gateway)

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection 4" source=static address=127.0.1.1 mask=255.0.0.0 gateway=127.0.1.1
The parameter is incorrect.
```

How to change the address of this loopback adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update "127.0.0.1" IP address to another loopback adapter's IP address. "127.0.0.1" is already reserved for the default loopback address of your main ethernet adapter. Try use other IP. The same command should work.

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection 4" source=static address=172.0.1.1 mask=255.0.0.0 gateway=172.0.1.1
```

Comment: In linux I can create loopback adapter with address 127.0.1.1 with gateway 255.0.0.0. How does this works there?
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.1.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
.